# How do I put API data into a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, hash, models

Currently I am using the Last.fm api to return concert data (returns a hash) in my controller, and in the view cycling through this hash to return the data I want.  I want this concert data to become more dynamic and put everything into a model.  How do I do this? Should I do this in the controller or somehow in the model?

Here is an example of my code

```
# app/controllers/events_controller.rb
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @events = @lastfm.geo.get_events("Chicago",0,5)
    respond_with @events
  end
end

# app/views/events/index.html.erb
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  Headliner: <%= event["artists"]["headliner"] %>
<% end %>
```

In this example I would would want and Event Model with headliner as a parameter, and put all 5 of the events into this model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's a good idea to have a model. There are several advantages as I can see

1 - You could access data as OO way as other objects

2 - if you have some business logics (Ex: calculations) you could do it in the model itself with out messing up your view

3 - it's clean and DRY

Example model class would be (this is not a working model, but just to give you an idea):

```
class Event
  attr_accessor :headliner


  def self.event_list(limit = 5)
    lastfm.geo.get_events("Chicago",0,limit) 
  end

end
```

So you can clean-up your view as

```
<% Event.each do |event| %>
   Headliner: event.headliner
<% end %>
```

Comment: This doesn't totally answer my question. I now understand a model is the right way to go, but how do I actually assign headliner in the model.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to thoroughly answer this question without more knowledge about the last.fm API. As a general rule, you want to keep most of your complex logic and relationship data in the model.

For example, you already know you need an `Event` model, but it also looks like you might need an `Artist` model as well. You might end up with something like this:

```
# app/models/artist.rb
class Artist
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    self.name = name
  end
end

# app/models/event.rb
class Event
  attr_accessor :artists

  def initialize(attributes)
    @attributes = attributes

    self.artists = attributes['artists'].map do |artist_name|
      Artist.new(artist_name)
    end
  end

  def headliner
    @headliner ||= self.artists.detect do |artist|
      @attributes['headliner'] == artist.name
    end
  end
end

# app/controllers/events_controller.rb
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @events = @lastfm.geo.get_events('Chicago', 0, 5).map do |event_attributes|
      Event.new(event_attributes)
    end

    respond_with @events
  end
end
```

You might also want to look into [`ActiveModel`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel.html), which has some helpful features for models that aren't database-backed and can't inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`.